# Call a function in one of the modules from a custom PHP file on my Drupal site

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to run a function in one of my module. This function is perfectly visible throughout my drupal site.

For one of my option, I have to run this function when colorbox loads. I have no idea which PHP file is called when the colorbox opens. I do know where the JS code is when colorbox opens, so what I did was this:-

```
...
...
inline:function(){
        $.get("sites/all/themes/my_theme/set_session2.php");
        return $.urlParam('inline', $(this).attr('href'));
      },
...
...
```

In this way, I can run a php file where I placed that function. Problem is that function is not visible in this PHP file.

Is there any way, I can get through this problem?

Best.

Comment: You cannot call a PHP function from JavaScript executed in the browser. What you can do is use JavaScript to make an HTTP request to your site. And have that request handle by custom PHP code. But this is not calling a PHP function from JavaScript.

Comment: Make an AJAX call to your script. If it works when you call url from your browser it will also works when called by AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

Just add these three lines in your custom PHP file.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()); 
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Works like a charm.